# “-/+ buffers/cache memory” used is always 0KB

Tags: vps, memory-usage, solusvm

I have an OpenVZ VPS with Ubuntu server 14.04.2 and I can access to a SolusVM control panel. Recently, "memory usage" is always 0 KB, and only "vswap usage" shows real swap usage.

if I run `free -k` i get

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        262144     121728     140416      69160          0     121728
-/+ buffers/cache:          0     262144
Swap:       131072          0     131072
```

and if I run `cat /proc/meminfo` I get:

```
MemTotal:         262144 kB
MemFree:          140416 kB
Cached:           121728 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Active:            53208 kB
Inactive:          62944 kB
Active(anon):      29864 kB
Inactive(anon):    29872 kB
Active(file):      23344 kB
Inactive(file):    33072 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:        131072 kB
SwapFree:         131072 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         59736 kB
Shmem:             69160 kB
Slab:               5568 kB
SReclaimable:       2064 kB
SUnreclaim:         3504 kB
```

Why is the "-/+ buffers/cache" memory usage  always zero?

Comment: i just find out that if i disable php5 mod from apache2 service "buffers/cache" memory usage shows correct usage... Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many reason to never use VPSes from providers that use OpenVZ. Stick with providers that use KVM or Xen and you won't have this problem.